# PHP number_format removes last zero

Tags: php

The PHP function removes the last character when it is an zero. What did i do wrong?

```
number_format($number,'0','','.');
```

Normal situation: 995.530

This situation shows: 995.53

Comment: try `number_format($number,3,'','.');`

Comment: You swapped separators. It's `number_format($number,3,'.','');`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sorry solutions does not work for me. 100000 gets 100, but need to be 100.000..

Comment: Search for "zero" in the responses [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) Came accros a couple of fixes!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
number_format($number,3,'.','');
```